# using socat to multiplex incoming tcp connection

Tags: socat

An external data provider makes a tcp connection to one of our servers.

I would like to use socat to 'multiplex' the incoming data so that multiple programs can receive data sent from the external data provider.

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:42000,reuseaddr,fork OPEN:/home/me/my.log,creat,append
```

happily accepts incoming data and puts it into a file.

What I'd like to do is something that will allow local programs to connect to a TCP port and begin to receive data that arrives from connections to the external port.  I tried

```
socat -u TCP4-LISTEN:42000,reuseaddr,fork TCP4-LISTEN:43000,reuseaddr
```

but that doesn't work.  I haven't been able to find any examples in the socat doco that seem relevant to back to back TCP servers.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be particularly hard to implement from scratch, but first it would be necessary to decide the ground rules - for example, what should happen if one client fails to accept data in a timely fashion?

Comment: What you tried works for me. In what way didn't it work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### With Bash process-substitution

Multiplexing from the shell can in general be achieved with coreutils `tee` and [Bash process-substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). So for example to have the socat-stream multiplexed to multiple pipelines do something like this:

```
socat -u tcp-l:42000,fork,reuseaddr system:'bash -c \"tee >(sed s/foo/bar/ > a) >(cat > b) > /dev/null\"'
```

Now if you send `foobar` to the server:

```
socat - tcp:localhost:42000 <<<fobar
```

Files `a` and `b` will contain:

*a*

> barbar

*b*

> foobar

#### With named pipes

If the pipelines are complicated and/or you want to avoid using Bash, you can use named pipes to improve readability and portability:

```
mkfifo x y
```

Create the reader processes:

```
sed s/foo/bar/ x > a &
cat y > b &
```

Start the server:

```
socat -u tcp-l:42000,fork,reuseaddr system:'tee x y > /dev/null'
```

Again, send `foobar` to the server:

```
echo foobar |  socat - tcp:localhost:42000
```

And the result is the same as in the above.

Answer (score 4):

I found ncat ( http://nmap.org/ncat/) to be flexible and easier to use. I suggest you give it a try. I cannot currently test it for you to find the exact command, but you can let it listen on 2 ports; for one port you use the -k option to accept multiple clients.

Comment: I found ncat to be the easiest for this kind of one-way multiplexing of TCP data, for example if the remote service is at port 5000 on example.com, run the following on your 'intermediate' server: `ncat -C example.com 5000 | ncat -l -k 5000` then you can connect to the intermediate server and receive data output by example.com (e.g. `nc intermediate.local 5000`).  According to [the docs](https://nmap.org/book/ncat-man-listen-options.html) this is good for up to 100 connections; 60 on Windows, adjustable by adding `-m <numconns>` to the listening ncat.

Comment: Just missed the edit window - the above is for the wrong direction (it assumes intermediate machine is a client connecting to example.com) for example.com connecting as a client to the intermediate machine use: `ncat -l 5000 | ncat -l -k 5001` and connect & receive data with `nc intermediate.local 5001`